# custom listview in android

Tags: android, listview

i find two different lessons of creatinf custom listview in android/ One of them uses ArrayAdapter the other one BaseAdapter/ Can someone explain what the differents between them and advise some simple lesson for dummies on creating custom listview/ thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom ListView Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305899/custom-listview-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

[Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

Good practice is view recycling.

Answer (score 2):

These are some of the tutorials i referred while creating my own list view..Hope  these helps you too

http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2011/01/31/android---create-a-custom-multi-line-listview-bound-to-an.aspx

http://appfulcrum.com/?p=234

http://www.androidpeople.com/listview

http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2009/02/15/multicolumn-listview-in-android/