# Custom listviews, 3 Strings per item?

Tags: java, android

How would I create custom listviews in Android? I've got items which have a title, smalltext and description. I'd like to create a listview from them where each item is the triple title, smalltext, description that would look like

```
**Item Heading**

Description bla bla bla

small text

**Item Heading**

Description bla bla bla

small text

**Item Heading**

Description bla bla bla

small text
```

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For doing this task you have to create your own custom list view, Custom Adapter.

See the example [here](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2009/07/custom-listview-for-android.html).

[saigeetham blog](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html). Saigeetham blog will help you to find what you want.

Comment: See the SO full discussion about Custom list views here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367434/custom-listview-in-android

Comment: See "Custom Adapter" and "Custom ListView" are TOTALLY different things. Building Custom Adapter is like shooting to mosquito with shotgun http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html especially if he is using db as data source ... first sample is so bad for android(fx: setters in Phone class)