# Custom ListView Android

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I have problem with my custom ListView.

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,
  this.dh.selectAll(),
  R.layout.custom_row_view,
  new String[] {"Icon","Chance","TeamID"},
  new int[] {R.id.text1,R.id.text2, R.id.text3});
  setListAdapter(adapter);
```

This is my simple adapter. I want put into them icons, can I do that?

Comment: Seems that you havent googled out before posting question here in SO or Google.

Comment: yes you can but you should be more specific ... how do you wana provide icon ? by Uri ? resource id ?

Comment: @Kartik we actualy don't know if he wants to use lazy image loading

Comment: @Selvin ,thx for answers, I have folder (drawable/flags/Albania.png) with many icons and I want put icons into my simpleadapter

Comment: @Kartik - the question is not a duplicate, even if he can use the same answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

yes you can ...

MyList.java:

```
package com.TestActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;


public class MyList extends ListActivity {

    final static ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>>();

    static{
        HashMap<String, Object> row  = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        row.put("Icon", R.drawable.flags_albania);
        row.put("Chance", "65%");
        row.put("TeamID", "Albania");
        data.add(row);
        row  = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        row.put("Icon", R.drawable.flags_rpa);
        row.put("Chance", "55%");
        row.put("TeamID", "RPA");
        data.add(row);
        row  = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        row.put("Icon", R.drawable.flags_polska);
        row.put("Chance", "100%");
        row.put("TeamID", "Polska :)");
        data.add(row);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,
                data,
                  R.layout.row,
                  new String[] {"Icon","Chance","TeamID"},
                  new int[] { R.id.imageView1, R.id.textView1,R.id.textView2});
       setListAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

res/layout/row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon" android:id="@+id/imageView1"/>
    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

put pngs with flags to res/drawable-hdpi/

flags_albania.png
flags_rpa.png
flags_polska.png

and you will get smthing like this:

[image]