# Adding two list in a single ListView having different adapters

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter

I want to add two list in a single List View. Both with different adapter.

i just found this one but i want something else

[how can set two adapter into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429420/how-can-set-two-adapter-into-a-list)

i want my list View like this one

[image]

is it possible..

Comment: Why do you want 2 adapters?

Comment: for two different views in same list view

Comment: If you just want to use 2 difference view, use adapter with with 2 viewtype. Read this post for more detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297299/reusing-views-in-android-listview-with-2-different-layouts

Comment: Why not simple inflate another xml?

Comment: it is a folder + song view i have one adapter for folder and another for song.

Comment: that would be something like a merge adapter. There are several available (or a single adapter with a mergecursor)

Comment: that looks more like an expandablelistview than like 2 adapters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U need to override getItemViewType and getViewTypeCount.

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
   return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   int type=0;
   if(getItem(position).isFolder())
     type=1;
   else{
     type=2;
   }
}
```

And than u inflate your xml files for 2 items. Please review this link.

[Add headers in a listView using ArrayAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25102519/add-headers-in-a-listview-using-arrayadapter)

And also u create common model include to two items.

```
public class CommonModel
{
   private FolderItem folderItem;
   private RadioItem radioItem;
   //getter and setter
}
```

For example if myList.get(position).getFolderItem equals null u return song item type and inflate your song view.

Comment: But this one is using only one adapter in it i want to use two adapters.

Comment: I dont undestand exactly why are u need to two adapter ? I think u should use single adapter and your adapter's model include two item type. I update my answer for add to simple model.

Comment: I too have the same problem  @user3307005  I have some values hard coded in my array adaptor and to that I want to add values from my firebaselistadaptor which is another adaptor and display them in one Lakeview..how can I do that?