# Implementation of custom list view

Tags: android, listview, mobile

ive been messing around in android and have made my first screen. Its nothing much, has some values and a button on it. When i click the button i am trying to laod a new page with a custom list view

for this purpose i am using some code i found on here at [Custom ListView Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305899/custom-listview-android) in one of the responses.

It lists the code for the class that builds and it also lists the xml which defines a row i assume?

What i am stuck with is, when i click the button on my interface, how do i get that list view shown in the example above to display as the next page? Is it simply just calling

`Intent intent = new Intent("com.testproj.MYLIST");...`

or do i need to build an interface of some sort then add it? I am really struggling to break the mould of traditional thought process from Java and its killing me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the code described in the link that you have referenced, you only have to do the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(InitialActivity.this, YourListViewActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

By the way, don't forget to reference `YourListViewActivity` in your manifest file.

```
<activity android:name="Package.YourListViewActivity">
</activity>
```

Comment: Edited the answer. Changed the first parameter of the `Intent`constructor to `ÌnitialActivity.this`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your list view is a ListActivity. See here to learn how to start an activity in Android: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#StartingAnActivity

I would also recommend to read the rest of the basic stuff on the developers site cited above.