# Design ListView In Android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I want to design listView like the this image link i have given below, https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8oQY.png, I have try all types of layout but still not able to define listview like this, please help me, 
my code is given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffff"
android:focusable="false"
android:id="@+id/notifTable"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:background="#08707D"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:id="@+id/tableRow1">
<ImageView
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:src="@drawable/alert"
    android:padding="5dp"
    /> 
 </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#08707D"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
>
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/label1"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:text="@string/hello_world"
  android:singleLine="true"
  android:layout_weight="0.5"
  android:textColor="@color/button"
  style="@style/listTextStyle"
       >
   </TextView>
   <TextView
     android:id="@+id/label2"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:text="@string/hello_world"
     android:singleLine="true"
      android:layout_weight="0.5"
      android:textColor="@color/button"
      >
    </TextView>

  </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: do you have a listview for each of this list_item_view

Comment: I add this layout with list view in my custom adapter

Comment: So are you not getting exactly the listview in the picture or you dont get anything at all

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UnVJL.png, I am getting the view in this way

Comment: The issue is that you are using a horizontal linear layout and you've set the width/height of your image view to 60dp. Your other linear layout (for the two texts) is then `adopting` this height of 60dp to show its content. Try setting the ImageView's width/height to `wrap_content` and see if that changes the way things are displayed. I would also recommend using RelativeLayout as your top-most layout and as the parent of your ImageView instead of a linear layout but that's more of a personal preference and an optimization tip.

Comment: Yes thankx, i have solved it using Relative layout

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) Control in your layout:

> ListView is a view group that displays a list of scrollable items. The
>   list items are automatically inserted to the list using an Adapter
>   that pulls content from a source such as an array or database query
>   and converts each item result into a view that's placed into the list.

You have not added the listview in your layout and more ref refer this example 
[Custom ListView Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305899/custom-listview-android)

And also you need to update the list item linearlayout

to

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#08707D"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label1"
            style="@style/listTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:textColor="@color/button" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:textColor="@color/button" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i have added ListView in my Custom adapter

Comment: what issue you are facing then?

Comment: i have solved it using RelativeLayout Thanku for help Bro.. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffff"
android:focusable="false"
android:id="@+id/notifTable"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<ImageView
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:src="@drawable/alert"
    android:padding="5dp"
    /> 

 <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="#08707D"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
 >
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/label1"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:text="@string/hello_world"
  android:singleLine="true"
  android:textColor="@color/button"
  style="@style/listTextStyle"
       >
   </TextView>
   <TextView
     android:id="@+id/label2"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/hello_world"
     android:singleLine="true"
      android:textColor="@color/button"
      >
    </TextView>
```