# Getting State of Toggle Button in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, togglebutton, android-togglebutton

I am trying to make a list view in which every item has two things, a description in textview and a toggle button. The details in the textview are dynamically loaded by the AsyncTask. At the end of the listview, I have inserted a button programatically. When that button is clicked, I need to get the data in all the textviews and the states of all the ToggleButtons. This is the Code that I have used:

XML FILE

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#dfdede"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggle1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:checked="true"
    android:text="ToggleButton" />

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/textView1"
    android:background="#49656565" />
```

```
public class MarkAttendance extends ListActivity {

String url = "http://192.168.173.1:8080/WebApplication1/androidrollsheet.jsp";
String pid = "";
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    pid = getIntent().getStringExtra("pid");
    new LoadRollSheet().execute();

    final ListView lv = getListView();
    Button submitButton = new Button(this);
    submitButton.setText("Submit");
    lv.addFooterView(submitButton);

    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ListAdapter adapter = lv.getAdapter();
            int total = adapter.getCount() - 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
                View rowview = adapter.getView(i, null, lv);
                TextView textView = (TextView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                ToggleButton toggle1 = (ToggleButton) rowview.findViewById(R.id.toggle1);
                String studentDetails = textView.getText().toString();
                String value = String.valueOf(toggle1.getText());
                Log.i("VALUE ???? ", value);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_mark_attendance, menu);
    return true;
}

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

class LoadRollSheet extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MarkAttendance.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET", params);
        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Entries: ", json.toString());
        //getting Sections array from JSON object
        JSONArray rollSheet = null;
        try {
            rollSheet = json.getJSONArray("RollSheet");
            //looping through all sections
            for (int i = 0; i < rollSheet.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject entry = rollSheet.getJSONObject(i);
                int rollNo = entry.getInt("rollNo");
                int userId = entry.getInt("userId");
                String studentName = entry.getString("studentName");

                String value = rollNo + "  " + studentName;
                array.add(value);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.activity_mark_attendance, R.id.textView1, array);
                setListAdapter(adapter);
                ((BaseAdapter) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

But, the problem is that I am able to correctly get the String in the text views but not the state of the toggle button. It always comes out to be the default state that is ON in this case. Any help with this will be very nice :(

Comment: Why don't you set a separate flag that changes whenever the button state changes?

Comment: Actually I dont know How many toggle buttons will appear as it totally depends on the number of entries I get from the JSON object

Comment: @durbnpoisn any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick;

```
final Boolean toggleState = toggle1.isChecked();
```

Comment: Code should be formatted with [Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: @223seneca sorry.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about, just trying to help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use [isChecked()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#isChecked%28%29), can't you?

**EDIT:** Another try, does this work (?) :

```
ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggle);
toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(isChecked));
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried using that but it gives the same value for all the toggle buttons same as the getText()

Comment: I'll just check and come

Comment: How do I do this for all the toggle buttons that appear ? I dont know the count

Comment: I suggest you to create your own adapter, it should be easier to set a listener on each toggle... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305899/custom-listview-android